# Can we construct a Karp reduction from a Cook reduction between NP problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, np-complete, reductions

We have had [several questions about the relation of Cook and Karp reductions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=cook+reduction+is%3Aquestion). It's clear that Cook reductions (polynomial-time Turing reductions) do not define the same notion of NP-completeness as Karp reductions (polynomial-time many-one reductions), which are usually used. In particular, Cook reductions can not separate NP from co-NP even if P $\neq$ NP. So we should not use Cook reductions in typical reduction proofs.

Now, students found a peer-reviewed work [1] that uses a Cook-reduction for showing that a problem is NP-hard. I did not give them full score for the reduction they took from there, but I wonder.

Since Cook reductions *do* define a similar notion of hardness as Karp reductions, I feel they *should* be able to separate P from NPC resp. co-NPC, assuming P $\neq$ NP. In particular, (something like) the following should be true:

$\qquad\displaystyle L_1 \in \mathrm{NP}, L_2 \in \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Karp}}, L_2 \leq_{\mathrm{Cook}} L_1 \implies L_1 \in \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Karp}}$.

The important nugget is that $L_1 \in \mathrm{NP}$ so above noted insensitivity is circumvented. We now "know" -- by definition of NPC -- that $L_2 \leq_{\mathrm{Karp}} L_1$.

As has been [noted by Vor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13483686#13483686), it's not that easy (notation adapted):

> Suppose that $L_1 \in \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Cook}}$, then by definition, for all languages $L_2 \in \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Karp}} \subseteq \mathrm{NP}$ we have $L_2 \leq_{\mathrm{Cook}} L_1$; and if the above implication is true then $L_1 \in \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Karp}}$ and thus $\mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Karp}} = \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Cook}}$ which is still an open question.

There may be other differences between the two NPCs but co-NP.

Failing that, are there any known (non-trivial) criteria for when having a Cook-reduction implies Karp-NP-hardness, i.e. do we know predicates $P$ with

$\qquad\displaystyle L_2 \in \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Karp}}, L_2 \leq_{\mathrm{Cook}} L_1, P(L_1,L_2) \implies L_1 \in \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Karp}}$?

---

1. [On the Complexity of Multiple Sequence Alignment](http://dx.doi.org/10.1089/cmb.1994.1.337) by L. Wang and T. Jiang (1994)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12756/discussion-between-raphael-and-vor)

Comment: Is your question if $\mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Karp}} = \mathrm{NPC}_{\mathrm{Cook}} \bigcap \mathrm{NP}$?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Similar, but not the same. I'm asking for a predicate $P$ which your variant would set to "$L_1 \in \mathrm{NP}$" (cf. first part of the question), i.e. if there are results with $P$ stronger than NP-membership.

Answer (score 4):

its a generally open TCS problem subject to ongoing research whether & the exact conditions Cook & Karp reductions are equivalent and is apparently closely related to the open NP=?coNP question & other complexity class separations eg E=?NE (wrt sparse languages).

here are two research papers on the subject & further leads on tcs.se via similar question:

- [Are Cook and Karp Ever the Same?](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/turing.pdf) Beigel, Fortnow
- [Cook vs. Karp-Levin: Seperating Completeness Notions If NP Is Not Small (1995)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.465) Lutz, Mayordomo
- [many one reductions vs Turing reductions to define NPC](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/138/many-one-reductions-vs-turing-reductions-to-define-npc), tcs.se

Comment: I'm not looking for the *exact* relation.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to mechanically turning a Cook-complete problem into a Karp-complete problem, there must be **something special** with the language itself.

For example, even a much restricted version of Cook reduction, namely negative reduction (reduce to one instance like Karp does, ask for answer, then negate), would require something special in the language $L$ to be easily turn into a standard Karp reduction.

We can say that if $L$ has **the following property**:

**Given any instance $x$, we can, in polynomial-time, produce $x'=f(x)$, such that $L(x)\neq L(x')$.**

So we can have a standard Karp reduction by first reduce to $g(x)$ by a negative reduction, then output $f(g(x))$.

As you can see, these properties are not normally seen in complexity theory, computability theory. **In conclusion, it is extremely unlikely to be able to turn Cook into Karp.**