# If you have a Cook reduction in both directions, do you also have a Karp reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

If there exists a Cook reduction of a decision problem $\mathcal{P}_1$ into another decision problem $\mathcal{P}_2$ and also a Cook reduction of $\mathcal{P}_2$ into $\mathcal{P}_1$, then is there also a Karp reduction (a polynomial transformation) between $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ (in both directions)?

These are the definitions I use:

> *Cook reduction*
> $\mathcal{P}_1$ polynomially reduces to $\mathcal{P}_2$ if there is a polynomial-time oracle algorithm for $\mathcal{P}_1$ using an oracle for $\mathcal{P}_2$.
>
> *Karp reduction*
> $\mathcal{P}_1=(X_1,Y_1)$ polynomially transforms to $\mathcal{P}_2=(X_2,Y_2)$ if there is a function $f:X_1\rightarrow X_2$ computable in polynomial time such that for all $x\in X_1$, $x\in Y_1$ if and only if $f(x)\in X_2$.

Comment: Also, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I already edited the question,  @RaphaeI get stuck cause my definiton of "NP-hard problem uses reduction (i.e. $\mathcal{P_1}$ is NP-hard if any NP decision problem can be polynomially transformed to $\mathcal{P_1}$", but the definitions that I find in internet uses polynomial reduction instead of polynoimal transformation

Comment: It is well known that the two types of reductions are not known to be equivalent and most believe they induce strictly different notions of hardness. See e.g. [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16386/98) and questions linked there, or [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/20074/98). That is probably what most sources are concerned with. However, you have more to work with here: $P_1$ and $P_2$ are *equally hard* w.r.t Cook reductions. Have you tried using that? What, specifically, have you tried towards *(dis)proving* the claim yourself?

Comment: Do you mean to restrict $P_1,P_2$ to be in NP, or do you allow them to be arbitrary?

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on whether you require both of $\mathcal{P}_1,\mathcal{P}_2$ to be in NP or not.

### If the problems need not be in NP

Then the answer to your question is "No".  There exist problems $\mathcal{P}_1,\mathcal{P}_2$ that are Cook-reducible (in both directions) but not Karp-reducible (in either direction)

In particular, consider $\mathcal{P}_1 = $ HALT (the Halting problem) and $\mathcal{P}_2 = \overline{\mathcal{P}_1}$ (its complement).  They are Cook-reducible (you just invoke the oracle and complement its answer), but not Karp-reducible.

(Similarly, if $\textsf{NP} \ne \textsf{coNP}$, then the answer is No: take $\mathcal{P}_1 = $ SAT and $\mathcal{P}_2 = $ TAUTOLOGY, so that $\mathcal{P}_1$ is NP-complete and $\mathcal{P}_2$ is coNP-complete.  They're Cook-reducible, but a Karp reduction would prove that $\textsf{NP} = \textsf{coNP}$ via a [standard argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP).)

### If the question is restricted to require both problems to be in NP

Then it's an open question; no one knows whether the answer is "Yes" or "No".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#Completeness_under_different_types_of_reduction and

- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/686/5038 and
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/138/5038 and
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3435/5038 and
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14379/5038 and
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16983/5038.

Comment: (As an independent matter:) ​ Due to the existence of Ladner's theorem, I would not be surprised if "If P≠NP then there is an NP problem that is not Karp-reducible to its complement." is true _and relativizes_ (although I'm not aware of any such result). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Ugh, can you please format this link list a little more nicely?

Comment: @Raphael, OK, done.  While we're on this topic, let me advocate for http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251183/160917 -- you might consider upvoting if you think it would help make this kind of answer look a bit nicer.